# Change text-nodes text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, textnode

How can I change text-nodes text?

#### HTML:

```
<p class='theClass'> bbb <a href=#> foo</a> aaa </p>
```

I'm trying to change 'aaa' and 'bbb' to `hello world`. I successed to select those nodes but couldn't change their text.

#### Jquery so far:

```
var $textNodes = $('.theClass').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/Pdb7e/)

What can I do with this `$textNodes` to change their text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `nodeValue` or `data` property of the text node. Both are equally valid and well supported:

```
$textNodes.each(function() {
    this.data = "CHANGED";
});
```

Incidentally, `Node.TEXT_NODE` does not exist in IE < 9, so you'd be better off simply using `3` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly edit a text node with jQuery.

Just use the native `data` or `nodeValue` property directly on the nodes.

```
$textNodes.each(function() {
    this.data = "Hello world";
 // this.nodeValue = "Hello world";
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pdb7e/1/)

Comment: Thats weird, couldn't find `data` in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/textnode)

Comment: It's a standard DOM property. It's under the `CharacterData` interface in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/CharacterData

Comment: @gdoron: Have you ever checked out [quirksmode's compatibility tables](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html)? I learned quite a bit of the API just from there.

Answer (score 1):

Found it after a lot of time in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/textnode):

This propery is called `nodeValue` not `value` for some stupid reason...

fixed JQuery:

```
var $textNodes = $('.theClass').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
}).each(function(){
    this.nodeValue = "hello World";
});
```

Fixed [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/Pdb7e/2/)

Comment: `nodeValue` is standard DOM property of `Node`s. `value` is a property of form controls that represents a different concept.