# How to change text inside span with jQuery, leaving other span contained nodes intact?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<span class="target">Change me <a class="changeme" href="#">now</a></span>
```

I'd like to change the text node (i.e. "Change me ") inside the span from jQuery, while leaving the nested `<a>` tag with all attributes etc. intact. My initial huch was to use `.text(...)` on the span node, but as it [turns out](http://api.jquery.com/text/) this will replace the whole inner part with the passed textual content.

I solved this with first cloning the `<a>` tag, then setting the new text content of `<span>` (which will remove the original `<a>` tag), and finally appending the cloned `<a>` tag to my `<span>`. This works, but feels such an overkill for a simple task like this. Btw. I can't guarantee that there will be an initial text node inside the span - it might be empty, just like:

```
<span class="target"><a class="changeme" href="#">now</a></span>
```

I did a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yx5Ju/1/) too. So, what would be the neat way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of **[In jQuery how can I change an element's text without changing its child elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106809)** or **[jQuery - setting an element's text only without removing other element (anchor)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156470)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$('a.changeme').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.target').contents().not(this).eq(0).replaceWith('Do it again ');
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eEMGz/

ref: http://api.jquery.com/contents/

**Update**:

I guess I read your question wrong, and you're trying to replace the text if it's already there and inject it otherwise. For this, try:

```
$('a.changeme').on('click', function() {
  var
    $tmp = $(this).closest('.target').contents().not(this).eq(0),
    dia = document.createTextNode('Do it again ');

  $tmp.length > 0 ? $tmp.replaceWith(dia) : $(dia).insertBefore(this);
});
```

​Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eEMGz/3/

Comment: It seems like this might be a good place to extend jQuery higher up in the code, just to keep the working code clean; do you think so?

Comment: @CodeJunkie I'm not sure. If this was just over and over again, then a plugin might be ok, but otherwise I'd stick without extending jquery for such little tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.contents()`:

```
//set the new text to replace the old text
var newText = 'New Text';

//bind `click` event handler to the `.changeme` elements
$('.changeme').on('click', function () {

    //iterate over the nodes in this `<span>` element
    $.each($(this).parent().contents(), function () {

        //if the type of this node is undefined then it's a text node and we want to replace it
        if (typeof this.tagName == 'undefined') {

            //to replace the node we can use `.replaceWith()`
            $(this).replaceWith(newText);
        }
    });
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/PURHA/1/

Some docs for ya:

- `.contents()`: http://api.jquery.com/contents
- `.replaceWith()`: http://api.jquery.com/replacewith
- `typeof`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

### Update

```
var newText = 'New Text';
$('a').on('click', function () {
    $.each($(this).parent().contents(), function () {
        if (typeof this.tagName == 'undefined') {

            //instead of replacing this node with the replacement string, just replace it with a blank string
            $(this).replaceWith('');
        }
    });

    //then add the replacement string to the `<span>` element regardless of it's initial state
    $(this).parent().prepend(newText);
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/PURHA/2/

Comment: "Btw. I can't guarantee that there will be an initial text node inside the span - it might be empty" this test case fails.

Comment: @AndrásSzepesházi I didn't realize you wanted to add the new string to empty containers as well. I updated my answer, here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/PURHA/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
var $textNode, $parent;
$('.changeme').on('click', function(){
    $parent = $(this).parent(); 
    $textNode= $parent.contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == 3;
    });
    if($textNode.length){
        $textNode.replaceWith('Content changed')
    }
    else{
        $parent.prepend('New content');
    }
});
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/yx5Ju/8/

Comment: you forgot to update your fiddle, but the code quoted above works nicely for both cases (i.e. having / not having) initial text.

Comment: One strange behavior is if there are text nodes on both sides of the `<a>` element they will both be replaced with the new text: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/yx5Ju/9/

Comment: @Jasper - If that is going to be the case then it can be handled in the code. OP will know it better if such condition exists.

Answer (score 1):

You step out of jQuery because it doesn't help you to deal with text nodes. The following will remove the first child of every `<span>` element with class "target" if and only if it exists and is a text node.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yx5Ju/11/

Code:

```
$('span.target').each(function() {
    var firstChild = this.firstChild;
    if (firstChild && firstChild.nodeType == 3) {
        firstChild.data = "Do it again";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! With a slight change this works for both cases I needed (both text replace and insert modes), http://jsfiddle.net/yx5Ju/12/

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect example I guess, but you could use [contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) function.

```
console.log($("span.target").contents()[0].data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the text into a span ... but ...

try this.
http://jsfiddle.net/Y8tMk/

```
$(function(){
    var txt = '';
    $('.target').contents().each(function(){
        if(this.nodeType==3){
                    this.textContent = 'done ';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: "Btw. I can't guarantee that there will be an initial text node inside the span - it might be empty" this test case fails. Otherwise cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the native (non-jquery) data property of the object. Updated jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/elgreg/yx5Ju/2/

Something like:

```
$('a.changeme3').click(function(){
    $('span.target3').contents().get(0).data = 'Do it again';
});
```

The contents() gets the innards and the get(0) gets us back to the original element and the .data is now a reference to the native js textnode. (I haven't tested this cross browser.)

This jsfiddle and answer are really just an expanded explanation of the answer to this question:
[Change text-nodes text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080407/change-text-nodes-text)

Comment: "Btw. I can't guarantee that there will be an initial text node inside the span - it might be empty" this test case fails. Otherwise cool.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.changeme').click(function() {                         
    var firstNode= $(this).parent().contents()[0];
        if( firstNode.nodeType==3){
        firstNode.nodeValue='New text';
    }
})
```

EDIT: not sure what layout rules you need, update to test only first node, otherwise adapt as needed

Comment: "Btw. I can't guarantee that there will be an initial text node inside the span - it might be empty" this test case fails. Otherwise cool.